# I struggle with JPanel, getWidth and getHeight

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I began this "Project" yesterday, I wanted to try out a program where a cube collided with the windows border. Seemed quite simple.

However, I struggle with the borders. I cant seem to get the "perfect" collison on the right side and bottom side of the window. The cube always goes a little further than expected.

I would assume the problem has something to do with my way of setting the size of the window? I am not certain but I did try some changes but it didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
package spritesInJava;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game {

public static JFrame myGame;
public static Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            createGame();
            timer.start();

        }


    });

}
public static void createGame() {

    myGame = new JFrame("Felicia");
    myGame.add(new MyPanel());
    myGame.pack();
    myGame.setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    myGame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    myGame.setVisible(true);
    myGame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
    MyPanel.loadImage();
}


}
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private static Image image; //Sprite
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1251340649341903871L;
private static ImageObserver observer;
private  int x = 50;
private int y = 50;
private int width = 200;
private int height = 100;
private int speedx = 2;
private int speedy = 2;

MyPanel() {

    Game.timer = new Timer(10,this);


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int screenWidth = Game.myGame.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = Game.myGame.getHeight();
    x+=speedx;
    y+=speedy;

    if(x >= screenWidth - width) {
        speedx = -speedx;

    }
    else if(x < 0 ) {
        speedx = -speedx;


    }

    if(y >= screenHeight- height ) {

        speedy = -speedy;
    }
    else if(y < 0 ) {
        speedy = -speedy;

    }

    repaint();

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //g.drawImage(image, x, y,width,height,observer);   //Uses the image that was loaded below and draws it.
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

public static void loadImage() {    //Load the image
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("photos/Felicia.png");
    image = icon.getImage();    //Set the "temp" ImageIcon icon to the public ImageIcon
}


}
```

The cube is supposed to hit one of the 4 borders and then change to "-speed", so if speed is 5 the speed shall be the total opposite (negative) and turn the other way. This works, but it does it a little bit too late. It seems like the collision system I made doesn't work

Sorry for putting all the code in one class!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, immediately, this seems wrong...

```
myGame.add(new MyPanel());
myGame.pack();
myGame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
myGame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
myGame.setVisible(true);
```

You `pack` the window before the preferred size has been set/determined, meaning that the window will want to assume the smallest size possible (as the `preferredSize` of the content is `0x0` by default).

You should avoid calling `setPreferredSize` as a general rule, but I would especially avoid using it on a `JFrame`.

Why?  Because a `JFrame` has decorations (window title and borders), which are inset into the window, so the viewable size is actually `frameSize - decorationInsets`, which becomes the core of your problem later.

So instead, I wold override `getPreferredSize` in your `MyPanel` and specify the "viewable" range of the component

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    //...

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
    }
```

Then in you main class you can just do...

```
myGame = new JFrame("Felicia");
myGame.add(new MyPanel());
myGame.pack();
myGame.setVisible(true);
```

And the API will work it out for you.

Ok, onto the next issue...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int screenWidth = Game.myGame.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = Game.myGame.getHeight();
```

`Game.myGame` is a `JFrame`, you're asking for the window size, but as I said earlier, frames have decorations, which are inset into the frame, reducing the viewable area available to your component.  Instead, you should be using the size of the component itself

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int screenWidth = getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getHeight();
```

#### Some suggestions...

I would argue the need for these...

```
public static JFrame myGame;
public static Timer timer;
```

But I have an issue with using `static` ;).  Making `myGame` `static` makes it to "easy" to access it's functionality from locations in your code which don't have any responsibility for doing so.

The `Timer` in this context is some what arguable, but I might be tempted to have a "update engine" which encapsulated it and the over update workflow, but that's me ;)

I would argue that this is not required (to be `static`)

```
public static void loadImage() {    //Load the image
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("photos/Felicia.png");
    image = icon.getImage();    //Set the "temp" ImageIcon icon to the public ImageIcon
}
```

The functionality should be created out by the component itself when it's created (or via some other "setup" phase).  I would also encourage the use of `ImageIO.read` as it will generate a `IOException` when something goes wrong, unlike `ImageIcon` which will fail silent.

As a side benefit (of `ImageIO.read`) you will also know when the image has completed loading, as the method won't return until it does, meaning you don't risk having some empty frames.

You don't need...

```
private static ImageObserver observer;
```

Nor does it need to be `static` (as been `private` it kind of defeats any benefit), but, `JPanel` is actually an `ImageObserver`, so you could just pass `this` to `drawImage`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the reply! I didn't know you could write "getWidth()" and "getHeight()" like that! I created myGame put the JPanel into that variable so I thought I had to reach into that and grab the height etc. But I guess "getWidth()" grabs it from "this"? The JPanel itself? I made the timer variable for keeping count of the time? I guess you mean that I don't need it because I never check the time? Makes sense, but I dont know how else to write it...

Comment: I will take your suggestions into consideration when editing it! It works when I have a cube now! However, the ImageIcon does NOT. Does that one have any different "size"? I haven't had time reading into it. And I haven't read about "pack" aswell. I just thought it was something I needed to put there :P But  thanks to your comment I have more knowledge regarding the size of a window and pack! Thank you!

Comment: The image I was using wasn't the right size! It had nothing with Java to do!